# Tags related to time and clocks

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

I believe that questions marked with [time-zone](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/time-zone)  should be re-tagged with [time](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/time), and [time-zone](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/time-zone) should then be made a synonym for [time](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/time). 
Mentioning the phrase "time zone" in the title and/or body of the question is enough.

[utc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/utc) (and other tags about specific time zones that might exist) must be deleted.

[clock](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/clock) is ambiguous on a forum about software and hardware, and in my opinion should be replaced with either [time](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/time) or [cpu](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cpu) (when it's about the CPU clock rate, as in [Slower cpu (pstate) = slower ram performance?](https://superuser.com/q/541480/33758)).

Comment: You've raised a good problem, but I think the proposed solution needs work.  [time] is a badly-abused meta tag.  I think we need to identify the major time-related tag uses and give them dedicated subject tags so they can serve a useful purpose.

Comment: Also fun: [tag:date] and [tag:time-date]  (Just missing [date][girlfriend])

Comment: We should blow up clock.